# Is solution of ODE $\frac{dx}{dt}=x\sin(x^2)$ blows up in finite time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The given ODE is $\frac{dx}{dt}=x\sin(x^2)$ with initial condition $x(0)=2$. The question is to find whether the solution to this ODE will blow up in finite time or not.
I tried using variable separable method but the integrand $\frac{1}{x\sin(x^2)}$ is complicated.
Is there any other way to proceed.
Any hint or help.
Thanks.

Comment: Just consider what the phase portrait looks like.

Comment: Try to work from $|x'|\le|x|$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I tried this inequality but independent variable is $t$.. So I am unable to make any conclusion

Comment: Are you familiar with the Grönwall lemma/theorem? /// You could also look for the equation after substitution $x(t)=e^{u(t)}$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann: Grönwall is overkill. Considering where the equilibria are, the system can't blow up at all.

Comment: @HansLundmark : Of course it is, but it is sufficient to force a solution. And yes, using the stratification supplied by the sine is more elegant.

Comment: @LutzLehmann sir can I say that by using inequality  $  |x’|\leq |x|$ that derivative is bounded in any bounded domain, so solution does not blow up in finite domain ?

Comment: @neelkanth : Yes, giving $|x(t)|\le |x(0)|e^{|t|}$. But every line $x(t)\equiv \pm\sqrt{k\pi}$, $k\in\Bbb N$ is also a solution and thus any other solution stays between its neighboring steady-state solutions.

Comment: @LutzLehmann ok sir thank you very much .